# Non-indexed ndb StringProperties are not displayed at new Developers Console

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

The new Developers Console is here for some time and the gaps with old AppEngine Console are almost closed. However today I have paid attention on some strange behavior of the new Cloud Datastore Viewer: my non-indexed ndb string properties are not shown (see two entities at the bottom):

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

However, the old good AppEngine Datastore Viewer shows all the properties perfectly:

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

The interesting thing is that the issue occurs only when I put the entity to Datastore using python NDB library. When I create an entity with non-indexed string properties directly from Developer Console, it is created and displayed well (see the first line at the first screenshot).

Also, string properties are displayed when I define StringProperty with (indexed=True).

Is this a bug or expected behavior?

Comment: This does look like a bug. Thanks for reporting it. I've passed it along to the Google Developers Console team.

Comment: Thank, Ed. Is there some common place to report bugs on Google Cloud platform?

Comment: For the Developers Console, there's a "Send feeback" in the lower-right corner that you can use. Other Google Cloud Platform products have their own trackers -- they're generally linked to that product's documentation.